# Positioning divs that will move when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that re sizes with the window. I want the words on my background image to represent links. My idea was to create divs that were empty and transparent and position them over the words in the background image and when that div was clicked, the corresponding link would be activated.

I am having trouble positioning my divs. I can't seem to get them to stay aligned with their word in the background image when the window is re resized.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="bespoke">
        I want this to always be aligned with "Bespoke" in the background image
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
    background: url(main.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

#bespoke {

}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DzC3V/1/

Note: if jQuery is the best way to accomplish this, I don't mind using it.

Comment: Is there something wrong with a standard image map?  Do they not scale?

Comment: Will image mapping work if the image is re sized when when the window is re sized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you won't need jquery. CSS and positioning with percentages should do the trick.
Try the following

```
#yourObeject {
     position: absolute;
     top: 30%;
     left: 30%;
}
```

it's tricky to position your div properly. but it should work

if this doesn't fit your needs you should really try doing an image Map and resize it with jquery

Comment: Didn't work with just CSS - needed jQuery. But your answer was the best one here.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to do this is to use media queries, its a bit of a drag, but it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image in a div 
And you can put the empty div on top of it using the z-index:1
So u have better control on both